# Content of byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

my problem is that I send to external device byte array like this:
`byte[] dataBuffer = new Byte[9] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};`
but when I read there these bytes, I get e.g. 2 when there should be 3. So it is always the left value. 
Is it possible that there is something else at the beginning of array? Null value?

Comment: How do you access your array ? It starts at index 0, so Byte[0] should be 1, maybe you try access it with Byte[1] ?

Comment: and no: a `byte[]` never contains `null`.

Comment: Your mathematical knowledge is probably a [few centuries out of date](http://www.yesiknowthat.com/who-invented-zero/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bytes array is `zero-indexed` you might be considering dataBuffer[1] as first element but infact you have dataBuffer[0] first element.

Comment: Now I see the problem. First element is repeated so others are shifted by one position. Now I don't see why, but it seems now that this is not C# code issue. Thanks.